NET8 MAUI WebView Javascript Cookie Access is Denied?
I have built a Multi Platform .NET8 MAUI application. Currently I am focusing on Windows 10.0.22621 and Android 14.
I have an HTML page (MauiAsset) loaded into the Source WebView.
In that HTML page there is some Javascript code similar to the tutorial at W3School: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
The problem is that I have run the application and successfully displayed the HTML page, but the Javascript scripts related to Cookies are all rejected.
I have searched a lot but most of the solutions are using C# code mechanism (Behind Page) or ViewModel MVVM to work with Cookies.
Or if you want to use Javascript, you have to use the mechanism of calling Javascript Function on C# Behind Code.
var passSomeValueCsharCodeBehind = "2024";
var resultValueFromJavascript = 
    await xNameWebViewControl.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(
            $"nameFunctionJavascript({passSomeValueCsharCodeBehind})"
    );
    //SetCookie(resultValueFromJavascript) from C# Behind

It's a hassle if I have a lot of other Functions, Javascript variables related to Cookie. Because I and a lot of people have to refactor the whole code.
So does anyone know how to get permission to use Javascript set/get Cookie on MAUI WebView?

Does it help How to enable cookie in webview for local js file?

@Liqun Shen-MSFT Thanks for your help.
I got this message in DevTools: Third-party cookie will be blocked in future Microsoft Edge versions as part of unpartitioned third-party cookie deprecation. It seems like Cookies are leaving us.
So my team and I decided to refactor the whole code and use Preferences or SecureStorage... It will take a lot of time but probably more robust than Cookies.

Thanks for your response. This may due to the concern over privacy and data tracking. If you want to use Preferences, here is the official doc , Preferences.
